# Add additional data to order information during checkout process

Tags: database, prestashop

I have prestashop website and during the checkout process when choosing the carrier I added a dropdown which contains additional information about shipping when you choose the certain carrier.

More specific: one carrier provide "self-service parcel terminals" service, where customer have to choose the final shipping destination(address) from where he'll pick up the product. The dropdown list contains about 30 choices.

I added dropdown with carrier information as a module and hooked it in hookDisplayBeforeCarrier hook.

How should I save this data into database and then display it in backoffice in orders section?

Comment: I don't know what your additional data is, but standard way is not adding dropdown item, but create as much shipping possibilities as needed. Depending on nature of your additional information, this might be not a solution (e.g. too many options). Please specify nature of this additional information to get better targeted answers.

Comment: When you choose specific carrier you have to choose the shipping destination(address) of this carrier. I think the carrier provided services call "self-service parcel terminals". The dropdown list contains about 30 choices.

Comment: I see... having 30 carriers for this wouldn't be nice solution indeed. Lame solution would be request from customer to specify destination in comment.
But to nicely solve this - using dropdown menu as you want, you will need to dig into PHP, modify checkout a bit to push this information to database. database modification is needed also. For skilled PHP programer, this should be a piece of cake.
I don't see any simpler way for this

Answer (score 0):

To fulfills your requirements, you need to use following hooks of PrestaShop.

1. processCarrier - To save the selection in a cookie or something temporarily
2. hookNewOrder - To fetch and save the selection into database on order place
3. displayBackOfficeHeader - To display the selection in back office order details.